# Отмена "новой" формы JQuery

Tags: jquery

Есть форма, которая уже прогружена при загрузке страницы

```
<form onsubmit="callback('recovery')">
                        <p>Забыли пароль ?</p>
                        <input type="login" name="login" placeholder="Никнейм" onchange="editValue('pc', 'login')"><br><br>
                        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Почта" onchange="editValue('pc', 'email')"><br><br>
                        <input type="hidden" class="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" />
                        <button>Восстановить</button>
                        <p>Еще нет аккаунта ?</p>
                        <a href="reg">Регистрация</a>
                    </form>
```

И при ее подтверждение JQuery отменяет эту форму данным кодом:

```
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.sendform = $(this);
});
```

Все было бы хорошо, НО в ответе должно приходить

```
<form onsubmit="callback('recovered')">
<input placeholder="Код с почты"/><br>
<input placeholder="Новый пароль"/><br>
<button style="background: green;">Ок</button>
</form>
```

И как раз эта форма при ее подтверждение не отменяется!
Повторюсь те формы, которые были прогружены работают адекватно.
А новая форма, которая была в ответе не подчиняется.

Answer (score 0):

Надеюсь на более правильную реализацию, но пока сделал так, вдруг кому поможет

В ответе получаю и в onsubmit еще дописываю в ручную отмену формы

```
<form onsubmit="callback('recovered'); event.preventDefault();">
<input placeholder="Код с почты"/><br>
<input placeholder="Новый пароль"/><br>
<button style="background: green;">Ок</button>
</form>
```